# How to delete the folder a batch file is stored and running completely?

Tags: batch-file, directory

I need to write a batch file which deletes itself, all files in folder of batch file and the folder in which the batch file is stored. I created a simple .bat, but it doesn't delete the batch file folder.

Where is my mistake?

```
@echo off
%~d0
cd %~d0%~p0

md %appdata%\UploadFiles

@xcopy "*.zip" "%appdata%\UploadFiles" /e /i /q /y
@RD /S /Q "%~dp0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this code:

```
@echo off
cd /D "%~dp0"

md "%appdata%\UploadFiles" 2>nul
xcopy "*.zip" "%appdata%\UploadFiles" /e /i /q /y

echo rd /S /Q "%~dp0">"%TEMP%\%~nx0"
echo del "%TEMP%\%~nx0">>"%TEMP%\%~nx0"

cd /D "%TEMP%"
"%TEMP%\%~nx0"
```

The batch file sets first current directory to directory of the batch file independent on current drive because of option `/D`.

Next the commands are executed for which this batch file is written.

Then the batch file creates another batch file in directory for temporary files which deletes the directory of the batch file and finally the created batch file in temporary files directory.

The current directory is changed once more to temporary files directory as Windows does not allow deleting a directory used by any running process as current directory.

Last the created batch file is executed which deletes itself resulting in an error message because command processor `cmd.exe` suddenly can't find the batch file anymore just processing. But depending on how the batch file was started, this error message is not visible and of course can be always ignored.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?` explaining `%~dp0` and `%~nx0`
- `cd /?`
- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `md /?`
- `rd /?`
- `xcopy /?`

And read also Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).

Comment: Hi,thanks for your fast reply. I see that is very good point. But your script unfortuantly don't work correctly. It's do the same as my. I mean it's delete all file in main folder with him self but don't delete the folder where he was exist. Do you know what i mean?

Comment: Well, if you double click in Windows Explorer on the batch file to execute it, the directory of the batch file is the current directory for Windows Explorer. I wrote in my answer that Windows blocks deletion of a folder if used as current directory by any running process. I suppose that this is the reason why the folder of the batch file is not deleted as you executed the batch file. There is no method to force a directory deletion if any process uses this folder or a subfolder as current working directory.

Comment: Ok, This is very important information for me. If isn't any other way to do this I must invent somting else.